# Expanding this method to write to the database

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Hi I followed a tutorial to implement a friend system. It all works find, but I need to post other columns to the row that just the id's. How would I expand that.

This is the method that is accessed when the add friend button is clicked

```
 public function getAdd($id){
    $user = User::where('id', $id)->first();

    //After passing all checks. Add other account
    Auth::user()->addFriend($user);

      echo "Sent";
  }
```

AddTenancy Method

```
public function addFriend(User $user){
      $this->friendsOf()->attach($user->id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the relationship is many-to-many between users. And you need to add additional data to the pivot.

Here's how you'd do that:

```
public function addFriend(User $user){
    $this->friendsOf()->attach($user->id, ['another_col' => 'some data']);
}
```

Replace `'another_col'` and `some data` with your column and your data. You can also add more than 1 column into the array.

Comment: I appreciate this. But the property column is in the controller, and I can't pass the data from a controller to a model